# Dummit and Foote Section 10.5 Prop 25 Proof (Part of The Splitting Lemma)

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

I'm trying to understand the proof of proposition 25 in section 10.5 of Dummit and Foote:

The short exact sequence
$$0 \to A \overset \psi \to B \overset \varphi \to C \to 0$$
of $R$-modules is split if and only if there is an $R$-module homomorphism $\mu:C \to B$ such that $\varphi \circ \mu$ is the identity map on $C$.

My question is this: The proof states that if $\mu$ is given define $C' = \mu(C)$. But how do we conclude $B \cong \psi(A) \oplus \mu(C)$?

Comment: This is what you have to prove; see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/975722/short-exact-sequence-of-modules?rq=1).

Comment: Note my edits to the question, and the typographical difference between $A \to^\psi B$ and $A \overset \psi \to B.$ Although this is MathJax rather than LaTeX and it cannot do most of what LaTeX can do, it handles most math notation as well as LaTeX does and you can find out things like this by googling things like "latex symbols" or "latex manual". $\qquad$

Comment: What definition of "split" is given?

Comment: @MichaelHardy The definition given in the text is that there exists a submodule C' such that $B \cong \psi(A) \oplus C'$ and $\varphi(C') \cong C$. I'm mainly trying to understand what the isomorphism $B \cong \psi(A) \oplus C'$ is.

Comment: I take it that by "a submodule $C'$" you mean "a submodule $C'$ of $B$.$ Being explicit about that can make things easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $B=\ker\phi+\operatorname{im}\mu$: every $b\in B$ can be written as $b=\underbrace{b-\mu\phi(b)}_{\in\ker\phi}+\underbrace{\mu\phi(b)}_{\in\textrm{im}\mu}$, indeed
\begin{equation}
\phi(\mu\phi-1_B)(b)=(\phi\mu)\phi(b)-\phi(b)=0.
\end{equation}
Moreover $\phi\mu(c)=0=1_C(c)=c\iff c=0$ and $\mu$ is injective (it has left inverse) i.e. $\textrm{im}\mu\cap\ker\phi=\lbrace0\rbrace$, therefore $B\simeq\psi(A)\oplus\mu(C)$ since $\psi(A)=\ker\phi$ by short exactness.

---

I'd like to get some sort of feedback: does my post answer to your question? If no, why? May I improve it? If yes, why haven't you accepted it yet? Thanks.